# Laravel Choosing one column in database conditionally

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a 2 columns in one of my table.

```
| mark_1 | mark_2 |
```

These marks are saved for 2 types of users in the system.

- **mark_1** is for **user_type_1**
- **mark_2** is for **user_type_2**

When fetching from this table, I need to conditionally get specific mark column (mark_1 or mark_2) as mark for each type of user. How to achieve this using Laravel eloquent model.

But want this in Eloquent such as when I query Mark::all() I need the necessary mark column value.

```
if($userType == 'student_1'){
  $marks = DB::table('marks')
                   ->select('user_id', DB::raw('marks_1 as marks'));
} else {
  $marks = DB::table('marks')
                   ->select('user_id', DB::raw('marks_2 as marks'));
}
```

Comment: Can you share the query that you have worked out?

Comment: I added sample code

Comment: do the same, change the `DB::table` to Model

Comment: Have a look at the query builder's [conditional clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#conditional-clauses).

Comment: Yes, it should work what is the issue here now?

Comment: How can I add this logic inside my Model. So I can just get Mark::all() and get the attributes as it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use 'addSelect' statement:

```
$query=User::query()->select('id');

if($userType == 'student_1')
$query=$query->addSelect('marks_1 as marks');
else
$query=$query->addSelect('marks_2 as marks');

$marks=$query->get();
```

more details about 'addSelect' in here:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#advanced-subqueries

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Accessors & Mutators** to get specify column value depend condition or append new attribubte to your model

check this link:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators